# Applications of the classification of finitely generated abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

The Theorem of Finitely Generated Groups is well known and is a good tool that allows one to find the possible structures of a abelian group.

I would like to know if there are some other interesting applications of this theorem.

I known that this result can be generalized to modules over a principal ideal domains, but I am looking for applications of the statement for groups.

The only one I known is the converse for the the Lagrange theorem, that is very standard.

Comment: I've never heard of "Theorem of Finitely Generated Groups." Please state it. Are you referring to the classification of finitely generated abelian groups?

Comment: Yes, the classification theorem..For a abelian group $A$, there exist $s$ and $d_1\mid\dots \mid d_r$ such that $A\cong \mathbb{Z}^s\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{d_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{d_r}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples. I think the most prominent is for computing tensor products.
It holds that:
$$ \mathbb{Z}_a \otimes \mathbb{Z}_b = \mathbb{Z}_{gcd(a,b)}  $$

Then you can use this identity to calculate tensors for all finitely generated abelian groups.

This might be especially interesting if you get into (co-)homology. At least in my eyes.

Comment: That is a very good one.. Thank you! If you have another example, I will like to know..

Answer (score 1):

> **Fact:** If $G$ is a finite abelian group, then $G \cong \mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathbb{C}^\times)$.

Here, $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is the group of complex numbers under multiplication and the group law on the hom-set is pointwise multiplication.

The most straightforward way to prove this is to:

1. Prove it is true for finite cyclic groups;
2. Prove $\mathrm{Hom}(H \times K,\mathbb{C}^\times) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(H,\mathbb{C}^\times) \times \mathrm{Hom}(K,\mathbb{C}^\times)$ for any groups $H,K$; and then
3. Apply the classification of F-GAG.